# Is there any method to find element by snap id in Snap svg?

Tags: javascript, raphael, snap.svg

In raphael there is a [Paper.getById()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById) method and it works well, but in Snap there is no such method and I can't find any analogue one.

I see that Snap sets for every element on the paper the unique id something like  this `pathSian06waj35` . But I can't find any information in docs how to use it to get an Element object by that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't typically use that at all, as its Snaps own reference, you would be more likely to set your own id (or it would be in the SVG markup), then access it your own variable, or via a css selector, its id, class etc.

Eg

```
var rect = s.rect(10,10,100,100).attr({ id: "myRect" });

//to access via id attribute
console.log( s.select('#myRect') );
// or
console.log( Snap("#myRect") );
```

Note: In early versions of Snap the id attribute didn't work correct, so make sure you are using version 3 onwards I think.

Comment: I see.But actually I don't need to generate an id for each element. It was really useful to use an raphaelid in Raphael.

Comment: Maybe if you modify why you need that in the question, rather than an attribute that would be exported or used via other applications etc, or an internal var. Not saying there isn't a use case, just hard to see it from the example.